# How to publish artifact into Azure Artifact

Tags: azure-devops

I have a file which it's created after Azure DevOps pipelines.

I want to save it.

I don't know how to publish artifacts from within an Azure DevOps Pipeline

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Please check if the several answers below can resolve your issue. Appreciate for marking it as an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to publish artifacts.

1.Use [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops#usage) or [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops).
A typical pattern for using this task is:

- Build something
- Copy build outputs to a staging directory
- Publish staged artifacts

For example:

```
steps:
- script: ./buildSomething.sh
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '_buildOutput/**'
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

2.Use [publish keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#publish) in YAML pipeline. The publish keyword is a shortcut for the Publish Pipeline Artifact task. For example:

```
steps:
- publish: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build
  artifact: WebApp
  displayName: Publish artifact WebApp
```

3.Azure CLI:

```
az pipelines runs artifact upload --artifact-name 'WebApp' --path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp --run-id '<run id here>'
```

You can also refer to the documents about [Publishing artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publishing-artifacts) and [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

4.If you want to publish artifacts to `Azure artifacts`. You can use task like `Universal Packages`. For example:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'Feed Name'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'test'
    versionOption: 'patch'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example ([Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines)):

1. Copy your file to the artifacts folder
2. Publish this folder as an artifact

   ```
   steps:
   - script: ./buildSomething.sh
   - task: CopyFiles@2
     inputs:
       contents: '_buildOutput/**'
       targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     inputs:
       pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
       artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
   ```

Comment: link does not work

Comment: @johnstaveley fixed